# What is the use of d-flex in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been trying to understand this d-flex from a very long time through documentation and other articles but still couldn't get any idea about it.
So, i am looking forward for a good simple explanation so that i can understand.

Answer (score 6):

Its a pre defined class that you can use directly so set `display: flex` over the element.